# Opentelemetry for jsonrpc via spring webflux

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux

The OTEL spec has json-rpc part. It requires to pass attributes that must be extraceted from request and responce bodies. I can't find out how to get access to request body in webflux. I've just found a posibility to add ExchangeFilterFunction where I can get access to a response body, but not request. Also, OTEL Context has Scope that must be opened and closed in same thread (if I'm not mistaken), therefore extracting request body should respect that.

Is there posibility to extract request body so that I can insert attributes to otel span from it?
Is there pass some request context that I can read inside ExchangeFilterFunction?

I've tried implement some kind of custom interceptor. I grab request before executing WebClient exchanging. At that moment I start a Span and then subscribe Mono/Flux in order to get access to response body (via doOnSuccess/doOnError). By that way I can't close Scope in the same Thread because WebClient uses own thread pool for exchanging.
Short code for explainig

```java
var request = ...
var jsonrpcOtelInterceptor = obtainInterceptor();
var publisher = doCall(request,...) //Mono/Flux
return publisher.doOnSubscribe(jsonrpcOtelInterceptor.before(request)) // <--- there main thread and start otel request context
         .doOnSuccess(response -> jsonrpcOtelInterceptor.after(response, null)) // <--- reactor's thread, there close request context and scope
         .doOnError(error -> jsonrpcOtelInterceptor.after(null, error));
```